# Launcher Problems

Tags: launcher, transparency

I'd like to be able to move the launcher to the bottom instead of the left and also make the launcher background fully  transparent. I looked around a bit but couldn't find a clear answer.

I would greatly appreciate any help on the subject.

thanks

LC

Comment: You might take a look at Lubuntu which is more configurable with respect to where the launcher/panel is placed.

Answer (score 1):

You can't, but you can switch launcher to Cairo-Dock for example.

http://www.howtogeek.com/202708/how-to-convert-the-unity-launcher-into-a-dock-style-launcher/

Good luck!

Comment: good answer, but it would be better if you included the steps in your answer instead of just a link.  Links can break making your answer useless.  Unity tweak(that is installed in your answer) can also be used to make the launcher transparent as well.

Comment: Yes, your right about links breaking. But especially for questions about visuals it is hard to get an idea of what's going to happen or how it will look like with steps alone. But your absolutely right, also about Unity tweak. A great tool for all kinds of tweaks, including making the launcher transparent, but no option for customizing the position.